# Facebook post photo to user timeline - permission review

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I want to post pictures from a Windows C# application (photobooth software) to a user wall.

Is this possible **without a review** of the app from Facebook? A review will be hard for me because I have hardware coupled software.

There are [guidelines](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/review) which I don't understand all.

As far as I understand there are/were different possibilities:

- `publish_stream` permission isn't possible any more
- `publish_actions`permission needs a review
- review is only possible for store and web apps
- posting via feed dialog is possible without any extended permissions?

Comment: Feed dialog is deprecated, but the Share dialog doesn’t need any additional permission.

Comment: can you give a link? there are so many outdated and different informations. I have no clue what is the current state.

Comment: You can not upload an actual photo via any dialog, you can only let users share a link that has the image set as thumbnail (and then maybe show the large version on your site, when other users follow that link). If you want to upload an actual photo, then you need to do it via API and ask for necessary permissions first.

Comment: this is the share button? When I have one computer different users login into their account there are restrictions?

Comment: [Share dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog) // Having a multitude of users log in on a single device is usually not recommendable – it can easily trigger Facebook’s mechanisms that try to detect fraudulent behavior. And if that happens, not only your app might get blocked, but users might get their login restricted as well (as a security measure), and then will have to take additional steps to be able to login to Facebook again the next time. You might be better of emailing the photos to the users, and offer them possibility to share on FB from there.

Comment: nearly every photobooth software does support multiple user login?